# Content Types with custom Javascript code

Tags: list, project-server, cascading

I am working on a project for my company, and there are a set of requirements handed down to me. One of the items is a bit concerning, since I'm not sure how possible it is.

They want to be able to create a total of three different content types for different kinds of documents. This is the easy part.

This is going to be going on the SharePoint Project Page for PWA. The idea is that these content types will be part of the template and have lists come pre-installed on the project sites.

The hard part is that they want to have these contain "Cascading Dropdowns". So for instance, if you select something from the first dropdown, the second dropdown will filter based on the value of the first dropdown. Below are some of the links that were given to me to support the requirements:

[Cascading Dropdown Example Link # 1](http://sharepointankur.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/two-level-cascading-drop-down-in-sharepoint-2013-using-spservices/)

[Cascading Dropdown Example Link # 2](http://spcd.codeplex.com/)

From what both of these documents are saying, there needs to be a third-party JavaScript library, as well as the javascript code to go along with it. To my knowledge, there is no way to include any kind of a code, such as javascript, in a content type.

There also needs to be a set of lists to allow the lookup fields to run and to have the filtering take place.

My last concern is that because this for the PWA SharePoint Project Site, there really isn't a site collection to host these on to use them globally. These lists are going to have to be replicated multiple times.

Are my assumptions correct? Is there any way to do this? If not, are there any alternate way of doing something similar to this?

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can include javascript with a content type using JSLink. This article includes a couple of ways to use JSLink. [Using JSLink with SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn745867.aspx)

Chris O'brien also has a nice tutorial where he uses JSLink with thirdparty library (jQuery) [Using JSLink to change UI of Sharepoint](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/using-jslink-to-change-ui-of-sharepoint_20.html)

Hope this helps you in the right direction